# O ScrollView horizontal de um TextView deslizar automaticamente ao inserir textos dinâmicos

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Eu tenho um `layout` simples de acordo com o mostrado abaixo que possui um `ScrollView` horizontal ao ultrapassar o limite do `TextView`.

Mas eu gostaria que quando fosse inserindo texto o foco do `TextView` ficasse sempre no último valor inserido e não precisasse rolar a barra pra ver o último valor inserido.

Tipo uma rolagem automática pra ir acompanhando os valores inseridos.

E voltar com a barra manualmente pro inicio caso precise.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer ?

**Activity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
     textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
     textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
   }
}
```

**xml**:

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
      android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="right">

      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/display0"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:editable="false"
           android:gravity="center|right" />
      </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente fazer assim:

```
ScrollView sc = ((ScrollView) R.findViewById(R.id.scroll);

sc.post(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
        sc.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: esse objeto "scroller" você criou onde ?

Comment: opa, é o próprio ScrollView. Simplifiquei o na declaração e esqueci ali.